# Powershell: How to copy files from one Directory to another

Tags: powershell

I am looking to copy a series of files from one directory to another.  Essentially the files are a series of zip folders that are simply changed versions of programs.  The files will be named something like: test_1_092.zip in the source directory and test_1_091.zip in the target directory.  I don't want the script to look at the numeric portion of the folder, simply the name.

Please forgive my lack of knowledge as this is my first foray into powershell scripting.  Any thoughts or need more info?

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: Not tried anything yet, simply trying to determine how to proceed. I have looked at some regex.  Still trying to wrap my head around the problem.  The flow should look like this: 1. Check to see that the test.zip file exists in both the source and target directory. 2. If the file exists in both, move the existing test.zip file to an archive directory in the target folder. 3. Copy the source test.zip file to the target directory.  Clear as mud I assume?

Comment: Please look at this: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Start with the copy command `copy file.txt newfile.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something to start with

```
(Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.zip").Name | where {$_ -like 'test_1_*'} | Move-Item -Destination .\1 -Force -WhatIf
```

Please confirm the output from –**whatif** , then remove it to perform the action.

***For the relation between the new and old name, please provide some more information.***